# How do I expand an inner product of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How would I go about expanding the inner product $$\langle av+bw,cx+dy\rangle?$$ I'm confused since you can only add to one side at a time. For example it makes sense to me that $$\langle av+bw,x\rangle=a\langle v,x\rangle+b\langle w,x\rangle,$$ but I'm confused as to how it's possible to have multiple terms as part of both terms.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be the first one. Simple typo, I will fix it!

Comment: Hint: $\langle av + bw, cx +dy \rangle = \langle av + bw, cx \rangle + \langle av + bw, dy \rangle$. Can you do it now?

Comment: That makes so much sense!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you understand the idea of linearity in the first argument, all you have to do is compute the bilinearity sequentially, as follows
$$
\langle av+bw,cx+dy\rangle=a\langle v,cx+dy\rangle + b\langle w,cx+dy\rangle
$$
Then now, consider linearity with the second argument, which gives
$$
\langle av+bw,cx+dy\rangle=ac\langle v,x\rangle + ad\langle v,y\rangle+bc\langle w,x\rangle + bd\langle w,y\rangle
$$

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this answer assumes the field is $\Bbb{R}$. Over $\Bbb{C}$, the result would be $$\langle av + bw, cx + dy \rangle = a\overline{c}\langle v, x\rangle + a \overline{d}\langle v, y \rangle + b \overline{c} \langle w, x \rangle + b \overline{d} \langle w, y \rangle.$$